# problems declaring Database helper object without onCreate() available

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access a DatabaseHelper class after hitting a button in a recyclerview.  The problem is that the Recycler Adapter i have the button in does not extend AppCompatView and i don't get the onCreate() method, so i can't use the below to declare a DatabaseHelper object to access by db functions.  I cannot use the 'this' keyword to get the current context.

I ususally do the below.  I extend AppCompatActivity to get the onCreate() method:

[image]

[image]

But i have to extend another class and can't use the 'this' keyword to get the current context and can't figure out how to access my DatabaseHelper class. 
[image]

The button i am trying to click is in a cardview recyclerview:
[image]

Can anyone help me get the current context in a different way so i can access database??? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s fairly simple. Make a parametrized constructor in GetInfoRecyclerAdapter class and from the main activity pass the context of the activity when creating adapter class object.

That would solve your issue.

Comment: I can use a different context than the GetInfoRecyclerAdapter?? maybe i don't understand contexts.  I have 2 activities MainActivity and ViewActivity.  So if i understand, pass the context of ViewActivity when it calls GetInfoRecyclerAdapter and use the context of ViewActivity???  Is that correct??